# ACS azure for published application

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, acs

Hy guys , 
I developed a WebForms application using VS 2012 . I've published it on Azure . 
After that I integrated ACS ( i've set the URL to my allready published application)
I published the application again , but it doesn't work .
After I've registered myself (for ex using Yahoo or LiveID) I've got this error :

Server Error in '/' Application.

The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[CryptographicException: The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.]
   System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope) +379
   System.IdentityModel.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Encode(Byte[] value) +52

[InvalidOperationException: ID1074: A CryptographicException occurred when attempting to encrypt the cookie using the ProtectedData API (see inner exception for details). If you are using IIS 7.5, this could be due to the loadUserProfile setting on the Application Pool being set to false. ]
   System.IdentityModel.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Encode(Byte[] value) +167
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[] cookie, Boolean outbound) +57
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(XmlWriter writer, SecurityToken token) +658
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SessionSecurityToken sessionToken) +86
   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(SessionSecurityToken sessionToken) +144
   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateSessionSecurityToken(SessionSecurityToken sessionToken, Boolean writeCookie) +82
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(SessionSecurityToken sessionToken, Boolean isSession) +216
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequestBase request) +860
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +369
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

What should i do ?
I've set the URL's correctly. I don't have in web.config any reffernces of "localhost"..
I don't know what I must set additionly for this to work..

Answer (score 0):

By default WIF uses DPAPI to encrypt cookies. Switch to cert based encryption. See this answer:

[Is it possible to run WIF without LoadUserProfile = True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464146/is-it-possible-to-run-wif-without-loaduserprofile-true/5465037#5465037)

Comment: Hello , I've entered the code from that answer in my global.asax file . But it's still not working . I have 2 problems : Warning 1 The element 'issuerNameRegistry' has invalid child element 'authority'. List of possible elements expected: 'trustedIssuers'. F:\sii\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Web.config 95 10 WebApplication5
Error 2 The type or namespace name 'FederationConfigurationCreatedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) F:\sii\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Global.asax.cs 19 62 WebApplication5
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Vittorio Bertocci answers the question here 
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/28/running-wif-based-apps-in-windows-azure-web-sites-4/

DPAPI is not available in the cloud web apps and 4.5 has a simple solutions